# Div the same size as viewport doesn't resize properly

Tags: jquery, window-resize

On initial page load I want a div to occupy the viewport space (like [this example](http://weareapostrophe.com.au/#intro)).  I'm using the following code:

```
$("#intro").height($(window).height());
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#intro").height($(window).height());
});
```

It stretches the div just fine, but the problem is that the div stays the same width and height when I resize the browser window, or go from portrait to landscape on mobile/tablet.  I have to reload the page to make the div adjust to the new viewport size.

I tried looking into the code of the example site but I ended up more confused.  I also tried a couple other suggestions I found here but none worked for me so far.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Look into the resize event on the window, use that to adjust the size of your div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion.  Looking into it this is what I ended up doing (and it works):

HTML

```
<body id="container">
    <div id="intro">
        Content that will occupy the whole viewport
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#container {height: 100%;}
#container #intro {height: 100%;}
#intro {width: 100%;overflow: hidden;}
```

And it worked for me.  Hope it helps someone else =)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Either use *CSS Media Queries* or jQuery mobile's `orientationchange` event that would do the work for you.

You can use `orientationchange` with use of jQuery mobile's plugin, add the below script:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js">
  </script>
```

and update to this script:

```
$(window).on('resize, orientationchange', function(){
    $("#intro").height($(window).height());
});
```